# How to show full text in a rectangle box when hovering over the mouse in C1FlexGrid?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am looking if there is a property on C1FlexGrid component control for showing full text in a rectangle box on top of the cell just like mouse hover. I tried looking in google but could not find anything that says there is a property.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "Showing full text in a [...]". Can you make a drawing or something to clarify what you are trying to obtain?

Comment: It's called a "ToolTip". Examples from ComponentOne: [link 1](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/userdatatooltipsfora4.html) and [link 2](http://our.componentone.com/2010/03/15/become-an-expert-part-6-data-manipulation-and-ui-enhancement/)